# Test a specific group of testcases with rake testtask

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, rake, rake-task, rakefile

Some tests require internet connection and some other don't. So they are divided into two test groups with different file name patterns. How to update below Rakefile so that they can be run separately with different rake tasks?

It seems the question/answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940349/testing-a-method-defined-in-a-rake-task) doesn't help in this case.

And the rakefile below runs all the test cases regardless what rake tasks are invoked on command line. Neither `rake test` nor `rake itest` works as expected.

The current Rakefile content is,

```
require 'rake/testtask'

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['test/test_*.rb']
end

Rake::TestTask.new do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['test/itest_*.rb']
end

desc "Run tests with no internet required"
task :default => :test

desc "Run tests need internet connection"
task :internet => :test
```

Comment: Tests requiring an internet connection are probably rather misplaced integration tests than unit tests. Unit tests should test *one single unit* only, so testing code that connects to the internet as well as the application on the other side of the connection is way beyond the scope of unit testing. I would mock out the remote requests in unit tests and move everything else (requiring the interwebs) to a separate integration suite. Then it is easy as pie to run them separately.

Comment: I agree with you. I've updated the question to reflect the efforts I've tried to achieve the goal, but I still can't do it. Comments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured out how to associate the different testtask with different rake task. The trick is adding a task name while creating a new testtask. Like this,

```
Rake::TestTask.new(:default) do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['test/test_*.rb']
end

Rake::TestTask.new(:internet) do |t|
  t.test_files = FileList['test/itest_*.rb']
end

desc "No internet connection required"
task :default => :test

desc "Needs internet connection"
task :internet => :test
```

So `rake internet` will just run the test cases that need internet connections.